# Taking output from command in Bash

Tags: bash, ping

I'm just trying to write a small script to see whether or not certain IP addresses are online as a link to an idea I had, I don't know much bash at all but I was wondering if anyone could help me out. It was to have an IP address pinged 2 times and if the results are say

```
--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1007ms
```

I would like it to `echo "OFFLINE"` and go onto pinging the next IP address, and if the results are say

```
--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
```

I would like it to `echo "ONLINE"` and continue onto the next IP address.

So is there any way to take the output of the ping and use it to determine what is echoed?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ping`'s exit status.  It will return `0` (i.e., success) if it is able to ping the target, and 1 otherwise.  So you could do

```
if ping -c 2 -q host1 &>/dev/null; then
    echo "ONLINE"
else
    echo "OFFLINE"
fi
```

but if you want to capture the output of a command you can use command substitution like

```
ping_output="$(ping -c2 host1)"
```

where the output of the command inside `$(...)` will be saved in the variable, here named `ping_output`

or if you wanted to use `grep` to see if the string appeared in the output you could pipe it:

```
if ping -c 2 host1 | grep -q " 0% packet loss"; then
    echo ONLINE
else
    echo OFFLINE
fi
```

we use `-q` to grep so it won't print the line that matches